# Why will OpenCV work in a Visual Studio C++ Console Application but not a Universal Windows Platform application?

Tags: opencv, uwp, visual-studio-2019, c++-cx

I am currently working on a Universal Windows Platform (C++/Cx) in Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 16.10.3. Part of this project requires the use of OpenCV to generate an image. I implemented this in a C++ console application and was able to get it working perfectly. Using [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/install-and-configure-opencv-4-2-0-in-windows-10-vc-d132c52063a1) as a guide, I downloaded and installed OpenCV 4.5.2 for Windows and configured it within my console application via the Visual Studio project properties.

Everything worked correctly until I moved the code into my UWP project. I copied the exact same settings for OpenCV from my console application into this UWP project, but when running it on Debug x64, I am receiving an "Unable to activate Windows Store app...'The target process aborted before activation completed." error when I try to run it. In the Debug console, it states that "A dependent dll was not found" but does not specify what DLL anywhere. If I run it on Debug x86, I get four LNK2019 errors that look like this, in addition to a warning about OpenCV being an x64 library but being ran in an x86 application:

`unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::error(int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,char const *,char const *,int)" (?error@cv@@YAXHABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PBD1H@Z) referenced in function "public: class cv::Vec<unsigned char,3> & __thiscall cv::Mat::at<class cv::Vec<unsigned char,3> >(class cv::Point_<int>)" (??$at@V?$Vec@E$02@cv@@@Mat@cv@@QAEAAV?$Vec@E$02@1@V?$Point_@H@1@@Z)`

In short, I am using the exact same code and project settings for OpenCV between the two projects, and it works in a console application but not a UWP application. I have tried to use an OpenCV package installed through NuGet instead, but it throws 11 errors similar to the one above. Does anyone know what may be wrong? Visual Studio is able to read the OpenCV library because the header files I am using appear under the External Dependencies folder in my Solution Explorer.

I am open to using a different method of OpenCV installation if that will work better, or even an alterative to OpenCV entirely if necessary.

Comment: TLDR: You can't use Win32 `*.lib` directly on UWP, you have some option solution now: 1. Port Win32 app to Store app with Desktop Bridge (not fully UWP, just package app to run on store) or 2. Use Vcpkg repository (this will completely build full UWP from source) instead of use pre-built static lib.

Comment: [How to: Use existing C++ code in a Universal Windows Platform app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?view=msvc-160)